# Gesture Recognizer with collection views

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` with a button as a supplementary `UICollectionReusableView`. When the button is tapped i add an instance of a subclass of `UILabel` as a subview to the collection view. the label instance has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. The gesture recognizers of the label are not being invoked due to the collection view. My `UILabel` subclass is as follows:

```
import UIKit

public class SJLabel: UILabel {

    // The pinch associated with the label
    private var pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!
    private(set) public var pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialSetUp()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialSetUp()
    }

    private func initialSetUp() {
        numberOfLines = 0

        pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePin:")
        addGestureRecognizer(pinch)

        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }
}

extension SJLabel {

    @objc private func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let location = recognizer.locationInView(superview)
        print(location)
    }

    @objc private func handlePin(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.numberOfTouches() != 2 {
            return
        }

        println("Handling")
    }
}
```